# How can I resolve this error when installing r packages?

Tags: r, r-sf, tmap

I want to try [this geopspatial mapping tutorial](http://zevross.com/blog/2018/10/02/creating-beautiful-demographic-maps-in-r-with-the-tidycensus-and-tmap-packages/#part-1-using-tidycensus-to-collect-us-census-data) but I can't get the `tmap` or `tmaptools` packages to install/load properly. Here are some screenshots of the installation.
[image: installing tmap and tmaptools] and [image: install2] and[image: install3] results in this problem when I try to load the libraries [image: install4]

If anyone could explain what the problem is and how I could fix it I would appreciate the help.

Comment: You have a program called `make` on your path, but it's not the one that R wants.  You have one from Embarcadero Technologies.  You need to install the Rtools collection, and put it earlier on the path than that `make`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user2554330 was right, there was a C compiler I had previously installed for a class that was interfering with the installation of the packages. I just renamed the directory of the compiler and everything worked.